# Javascript Ascii Encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, ascii

How to convert a JavaScript string to byte array using ASCII encoding?

In C#, it is done as:

```
 var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
 byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(string);
```

I want to do the same in JavaScript for my nodejs server

Comment: You need to post the code you have already tried and explain where you are getting stuck.  Please read [How to Ask a Good Question] and include an [mcve] in your question

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_str_encoding

Answer (score 8):

For Node.js this is fairly easy:

```
var keyByte = new Buffer(string, "ascii");
```

Buffer is a container of bytes, and can be treated as an array:

```
var bytes = new Buffer("Hello, world", "ascii");
console.log(bytes[3]);  //writes 108
```

Most of the network and filesystem APIs take and return buffers

Answer (score 6):

Update for NodeJS

```
const str = 'Hello world';
const buf = Buffer.from(str, 'ascii');
console.log(buf.toString('hex'));
console.log(buf.toString('base64'));
```